# Count the number of times a value changes in a variable for specific values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple rows representing repeated measures of the same individuals and then I am having a variable that represents some sequences coded from 1-5.

I want to find out how many times (number of events) across all individuals number 1, 2 and 3 appear after 4 and 5 in the P1 variable.

As a final product I want to have a dataframe where it will have as variables the category 4 and 5
and as rows the categories 1, 2 and 3 and it will show how many events category 4 had until it gets interrupted by either 1, 2 and 3 category and how many events category 5 had until it gets interrupted by either 1, 2 or 3 category.

Here is a small subset of my dataset

```
df <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6)),
             P1 = c(1,5,2,4,1,5,2,4,2,5,1,4,2,4,1,5,3,5,1,4,2,5,1,4,1))
```

What I want is either a dataframe or some sort of results like the following meaning that after number 4 there were 3 events of number "1", 3 events of number "2" and 0 events of number "3".

```
   Category_4    Category_5
1       3              2
2       3              2
3       0              1
```

Is there a way to do it with dplyr?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you write, "after number 4 there were 3 events of number "1"... ,what do you mean by number? Can you use the variables names (ID and P1) in the question instead?

Comment: Hey, sorry maybe I did not explain it very well. Diregard the ID column. I want to find how many times the number 1, 2 and 3 appear after the numbers 4 and 5 in the P1 variable. Because 1,2,3,4 and 5 values are categories in that variable. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can ignore `ID`, since your "after" seems to be predicated on "within each person". Without that grouping, then your numbers would be significantly higher, since `P1[2]` is a 5 and `P1[4]` is a 4.

Comment: Hey, but I do not want to use ID for anything. It is just how my dataset is. I am only interested in finding how many times 1, 2 and 3 where followed after 4 and 5.

Comment: @user13069688 The expected output numbers seems to be incorrect if I follow your logic

Comment: Hey, can you give an example? I can test it.

Comment: @user13069688 if i use your logic, whether grouped by 'ID' or not, it gives a different frequency. i.e. `df %>% summarise(Category_4 = replace(P1, row_number() <= match(4, P1), NA), Category_5 = replace(P1, row_number() <= match(5, P1), NA)) %>% na.omit() %>% map(table)`

Comment: I think this is wrong. Maybe I do not explain the questions correct. In the vector / variable P1 I want to find how many times number 1 is repeated after number 4 and 5. And then again how many times number two is repeated after number 4 and 5 and how many times number 3 is repeated after number 4 and 5 :)

Comment: @user13069688 If you see the code, I used `match` to find the index of first occurence of 4 and assign all those above 4 to NA and then I got the table on the rest.  Similarly for the number 5.  Maybe you didn't explain the logic correctly (If you add a group_by ID, then it does the same within each ID

Comment: @user13069688 Did you meant the ID value 1, 2, 3 or the values in P1 as 1, 2, 3

Comment: The values in the P1. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user13069688 unfortunately, the logic is not adding up to your expected output frequency numbers.  If you can explain how you got the numbers in expected  based on input, it would be great.

Comment: For example if you look at all the fives (5) in the P1 variable you can see that after the first 5 there is the number two (2) and then in the next five (5) there is again the number two (2). Then number two (2) is not repeated again after the number 5. Number 1 is repeated 2 times as well after the number 5. And again number 3 is repeated only one time after the number five. I want to find a way to calculate that. I think the expected results is correct.

Comment: @user13069688 I guess now I got your logic.  I was just looking for the total count instead of the adjacent elements.  Try the soluiton in the posted one

Comment: For the Category_5, I get 3 instead of 2 for 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for the adjacent element that matches, then get the `lag` and do a `count`, and reshape to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(P2 = lag(P1)) %>%
  filter(P1 %in% c(4, 5)) %>%
  count(P1 = str_c("Category_", P1), P2) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = P1, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     P2 Category_4 Category_5
  <dbl>      <int>      <int>
1     1          3          3
2     2          3          2
3     3          0          1
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted :) Much appreciated. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hey, I am having another question. What if we wanted to group_by() per ID. So we will have the same results but actually the lag() function would calculate only the sequences per individuals and then add the number of events of all individuals together? Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @user13069688 you may need to add `df %>% group_by(ID) %>%..` before the `lag` column